# Do I need more events when timing multiple work-items?

Tags: opencl, nvidia, gpgpu

If I have more than one work-item to execute some kernel code, do I need to have more events to track the execution time for each work-item?

I have some strange results, 1 work-item takes about 4 seconds to execute and 100 work-items also take about 4 seconds to execute. I can't see how this could be possible since my Nvidia GeForce GT 525M only has 2 compute units, each with 48 processing elements. This leads me to believe the event I listed as an argument in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel tracks only one work-item. Is that true and if so, how can I get it to track all the work-items?

This is what the Khronos user guide says about the event argument in clEnqueueNDRangeKernel:

> *event* returns an event object that identifies this particular kernel execution instance

What is the meaning of "this particular kernel execution instance"? Isn't that a single work-item?

EDIT:
Relevant host code:

```
static const size_t numberOfWorkItems = 48;
const size_t globalWorkSize[] = { numberOfWorkItems, 0, 0 };

cl_event events;
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, &events);
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, memobj, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), val, 0, NULL, NULL);

clWaitForEvents(1, &events);
cl_ulong time_start;
cl_ulong time_end;

clGetEventProfilingInfo(events, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_start, NULL);
clGetEventProfilingInfo(events, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong), &time_end, NULL);

double nanoSeconds = (double) (time_end - time_start);
printf("OpenCl Execution time is: %f milliseconds \n",nanoSeconds / 1000000.0);
printf("Result: %lu\n", val[0]);
```

Kernel code:

```
kernel void parallel_operation(__global ulong *val) {
    size_t i = get_global_id(0);
    int n = 48;
    local unsigned int result[48];
    for (int z = 0; z < n; z++) {
        result[z] = 0;
    }
    // here comes the long operation
    for (ulong k = 0; k < 2000; k++) {
        for (ulong j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
            result[i] += (j * 3) % 5;
        }
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if (i == 0) {
        for (int z = 1; z < n; z++) {
            result[0] += result[z];
        }
        *val = result[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the results change if you use CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START?

Comment: @Conradin No, still about 4 seconds in both cases.

Comment: Interesting. From my understanding the execution time should not be the same. Have you tried increasing the number of work-items beyond 100 to look if the execution time increases then? Also, are you changing `n` in the kernel when you change the number of work-items?

Comment: @Conradin Yes, I always change n to match the number of work-items. When I increase to 900 work-items it takes about 5,5 seconds.

Comment: I guess these timings come from the way the work-items are scheduled on the GPU. I unfortunately do not know how this works in detail. If you want to find out more about it, I suggest that you run extensive tests with different work sizes and maybe you can find a pattern at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are measuring the execution time of your entire kernel function. Or in other words, the time between the first work-item starts and the last work-item finishes. To my knowledge there is no possibility to measure the execution time of one single work-item in OpenCL.

Comment: If that's right, do you have any idea why I would be getting these numbers? I always assumed one work-item would map to one processing element, that would in theory make it possible to have 48 concurrent work-items, 96 if all cores were used, but how could a 100 execute concurrently when there's no physical space to do it?

Comment: If you use more work-items than can fit on the hardware they are executed in chunks. For example, if you have 100 work-items but can only fit 48 they would most likely be executed in two groups of 48 and one group of 4.

Comment: Wouldn't then the time to execute 48+48+4 be at least double the time to execute just 48?

Comment: It depends on how much work is done by each work-item. If you use 48 work-items instead of 96 for a fixed problem size, then each of the 48 work-items will have to do twice as much work, thus having a longer execution time.

Comment: In my case, all work-items are doing the same operation. It's not a real life scenario, I just want to figure out how the work-items map to the hardware by timing them. So 48 items do the same thing, 96 items do the same thing. Why do they take the same time?

Comment: That I don't know, can you add the entire code to your question?